# UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library

Tags: java, windows, exception, native, unsatisfiedlinkerror

I have created a jar file witch uses `autohotkey.dll` library. Jar runs smoothly on my main pc and laptop, but now I'm trying to use it on pc that has freshly installed windows 10 and I'm getting this error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to
>   load library 'AutoHotkey': Can't obtain InputStream for
>   win32-x86-64/AutoHotkey.dll
>       at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.loadLibrary(NativeLibrary.java:271)
>       at com.sun.jna.NativeLibrary.getInstance(NativeLibrary.java:398)
>       at com.sun.jna.Library$Handler.(Library.java:147)
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:412)
>       at com.sun.jna.Native.loadLibrary(Native.java:391)
>       at DllController.(DllController.java:26)
>       at UI.main(UI.java:113)

DLL file is located in the same folder as the jar file.

I have tried the following:

- Using both 32 and 64-bit versions of JRE
- Installed visual c++ redistributable package (both 32 and 64 bit)
- Also tried running the jar by the following command:

> java "-Djava.library.path=C:\runnablegui\new" -jar C:\runnablegui\new\as.jar

Screenshot from Process Monitor involving the Autohotkey.dll operations:
[image: Screenshot from Process Monitor involving the Autohotkey.dll operations]

Comment: Is that a typo here (or in your command)? `"-Djava.library.path= C:\runnablegui"` should be `"-Djava.library.path=C:\runnablegui"` - also, double check the folder structure on a working machine (it seems that dll should be in a sub-folder).

Comment: yes, there was a typo but it did not have any effect. I tried to move the dll to the sub folder on the working pc, but that it also starts to give the same error.

Comment: Use Sysinternals Process Monitor to check in what path the Java process actually searches for the dll (filter for the Java.exe process and only file operations).

Comment: I added the screenshot from the process monitor. If I understood correctly the dll is read from C:\runnablegui

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I did not have the newes version ov vc_redist installed